# Angular tests - Exclude specific spec files

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have errors in some spec files of Angular project and want to exclude them from compilation.

I've put these files in `exclude` of `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/ms-dialog.spec.ts"  // Should be excluded
  ]
}
```

But when I execute `ng test` I get the following error:

```
./src/app/core/models/ms-dialog.spec.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: /home/user/Documents/Projects/my-project/src/app/core/models/ms-dialog.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

May be the reason in my `tsconfig.base.json` file:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": [
        "../node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"
      ],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["../node_modules/core-js/es/*"],
      "@env": ["./environments/environment"],
      "@shared/*": ["./app/shared/*"],
      "@core/*": ["./app/core/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Also there's my `test.ts`:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
});
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Comment: maybe `xdescribe` could help you? this marks a describe in a way to skip all test inside of it

Comment: @Andrei, unfortunately, no, because there's a TS error in my spec file. And there's a lot of them in my project. I want to exclude them instead of spending time on fixing them now

Comment: you can leave tsconfig as is, but modify test.ts to not require the files you don't want to

Comment: @Andrei, I've already tried this (yes, in `test.ts`), but I get error from all spec files: `<file> is missing from the TypeScript compilation`

Comment: have you tried `context.keys().filter(...filterlogic...).map(context)`?